Polar coordinate plot incorrectly plotting with PGF Plots
I'm trying to plot a logarithmic spiral along with a straight line in a tikz picture, but at least one of them is incorrect and I don't know why. Here is a picture of how it should look from Desmos:
Here is how it is looking in Latex:
The problem being the line and the curve are not tangent at (1,0). I believe it because the curve is not plotted correctly. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?
Here is my code:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis} [
            xtick={0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315}, 
            xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\pi$, $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{7\pi}{4}$},
            ymax=1,
            ylabel=$r(0)$,
            y label style={anchor=north},
            minor y tick num=0,
            ytick=\empty
        ]
        \addplot [domain=0:720, samples=720, red, very thick] {e^(-x*tan(pi/3))};
        \addplot [domain=-4:4, samples=100, black, thick, dotted, data cs=cart] {-x/sqrt(3) + 1/sqrt(3)};
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


You're more likely to get some help if you complete your example with the appropriate packages so that we can copy and paste.

You should write {e^(-rad(x)*tan(60))} instead of {e^(-x*tan(pi/3))}:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis} [
       xtick={0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315}, 
       xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\pi$, $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{7\pi}{4}$},
       ymax=1,
       ylabel=$r(0)$,
       y label style={anchor=north},
       minor y tick num=0,
       ytick=\empty
       ]
   \addplot [
      domain=0:360, 
      samples=360, 
      red, 
      very thick,
      ] {e^(-rad(x)*tan(60))};
   \addplot [
      domain=-4:4, 
      samples=100, 
      black, 
      thick, 
      dotted,
      data cs=cart,
      ] {-x/sqrt(3) + 1/sqrt(3)};
   \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

tan(pi/3 r) or sqrt(3) can be written instead of tan(60).

Another possible solution:
\addplot [
    domain=0:2*pi, 
    samples=360, 
    red, 
    very thick,
    data cs=polarrad,
 ] {exp(-x*tan(pi/3 r))};

